# Linear regression model, SCE,SCT,SCM and model's error

Tags: r, regression, modeling, linear-model, error

Could you please check if what I've done is correct? and how could I improve some of them? Thank you in advance.

> Suppose I have the following data (the original data its like 20 data with decimal numbers):
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
> y &2&4&3&70&9  \\
> \hline
> x & 0.24&21&33&11&10  
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> 1. Draw a dispersion diagram of the data.
> 2. Adjust a simple linear regression model.
> 3. Find the SSE,SCModel, SCTotal.
> 4. Find the model's errors.

Solution.

1. Using the instruction `plot(x,y,xlab="These are x's",ylab="These are y's")`.
2. I think we want to find $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in our segment line, that is we need to calculate $\hat \beta_0=\frac{(\sum y_i)(\sum x_i^2)-(\sum x_iy_i)(\sum x_i)}{n\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}$ and $\hat \beta_1=\frac{n(\sum x_iy_i)-(\sum x_i)(\sum y_i)}{n\sum x_i^2-(\sum x_i)^2}$ with $n=5$ and substitute them in the model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x$

Am I correct?

3. I think this is calculated with $SSE=y'(I-M)y,\ where \ y=(2,4,3,70,9)',M=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and X=$\left(
       \begin{matrix}
       1 & .24 \\
       1 & 21 \\
       1 & 33 \\
       1 & 11 \\
       1 & 10
       \end{matrix}\right)
   $

$SCTotal=SSE+SSModel$ and $SCTotal=y'y$ so $SSModel$ can be calculated with $SCTotal-SSE$

Am I correct?

4. Here am I asked to find  $error=y-\hat y$ right?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is called scatter plot generally.
2. I would replace "Adjust" by "Fit"

Get the $\hat\beta_1$ first, then $\hat\beta_0 = \bar y - \hat\beta_1 \bar x$. Your $\hat\beta_0$ is complicated and I did not verify it.

3. Suppose you mixed up SC and SS. All of them should be SS.
   SSTotal = $(y-\bar y)'(y-\bar y)$
4. In the simple linear regression model
   $$ y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon $$
   $\epsilon$ is called error or error term. Its estimate is $y-\hat y$ and is called residual.

The question "Find the model's error" maybe means to find something that violates the assumptions of simple linear regression. For example the linearity between $y$ and $x$.

Comment: Hi, I was observing and I wonder why $\hat\beta_0 = \bar y - \hat\beta_1 \bar x$ ? Why the equality holds? Why did you take $\overline y$ and $\overline x$?

Comment: By least square method, you get that $\hat \beta_0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression.  Which equality holds?  Taking $bar y$ and $\bar x$ are easy for calculation?

Comment: Ah I see, I did not know the alternative way to calculate $\hat\beta_0: (\hat\beta_0 = \bar y - \hat\beta_1 \bar x)$. I was referring to that same equality $(\hat\beta_0 = \bar y - \hat\beta_1 \bar x)$. I think yes, $\overline x,\overline y$ are easy to calculate using R or other software.

Comment: Any other questions? My answers are understandable?

Comment: I got it 1 and 2. I am analyzing 3. (Patience please :)

Comment: I didn't know SSTotal can be calculated with $(y-\bar y)'(y-\bar y)$. But the way I propose to calculated SSTotal,SSE and SSM is also correct, right?

Comment: No. $\sum y^2 \ne \sum (y-\bar y)^2$. Others are correct.

Comment: ok, so SSE its correct. And I should use $\sum(y-\overline y)^2$ instead of $\sum y^2.$ Though I don't know why my professor said $SST=y'y..$

Comment: In 4. What do you mean with: "to find something that violates the assumptions of simple linear regression. For example the linearity between y and x." Do you mean something like having $x^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is what I mean. But question 4 itself is problematic.

Comment: Why is itself problematic?

Comment: Maybe it is just for me. I cannot figure out exactly  what that question is asked for. It is possible that your understanding $y-\hat y$ is correct, and also mu guess of $x^2$ is correct/

Comment: I see, though I think it's easier to suppose your first assumption: $\epsilon=y-\hat y$. Which (supposing $\hat\beta_0=5,\hat\beta_1=10$) would be $\epsilon=y-5-10x$, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to calculate 5 $\epsilon$s.

Comment: 5$\epsilon$ s? its just one $\epsilon$ no?

Comment: I mean we would get one single line segment from all the 5ys and 5xs, hence just one $\epsilon$

Comment: See your table. you have 5 $y$s and 5$x$s, so you should have 5 $\epsilon$s.

Comment: So will there be 5 segment lines?

Comment: supposing $\hat β_0=5,\hat β_1=10$, then  $ϵ_1=2−5−10*0.24 = -5.4$,  $ϵ_2=4−5−10*21 = -211$, ...

Comment: ah got it now:)